# Как получить роль в Discord при помощи бота python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord

Я делаю Дискорд бота на питон 3.8. Если написать какую-то команду в дискорде боту, то он должен автора этого сообщения "наградить" ролью. Но так не происходит. Что я делаю не так?

P.s. Бот должен давать роли при отправке ему сообщения БЕЗ РЕАКЦИЙ И КНОПОК

Вот код:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("$ок"):
        on_member_join()
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member,message):
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 'id of role')
        await member.add_roles (message.author, role)
client.run("token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня есть мой готовый код но у меня с БД:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):

    cursor.execute(f'SELECT wlc_role_t_or_f FROM public."myBD" WHERE guild_id = {member.guild.id};')
    on_or_off = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()

    cursor.execute(f'SELECT wlc_role FROM public."myBD" WHERE guild_id = {member.guild.id};')
    role = cursor.fetchone()
    conn.commit()

    role_1 = member.guild.get_role(role[0])

    if f'{on_or_off[0]}' == str('True'):
        await member.add_roles(role_1)
    elif f'{on_or_off[0]}' == str('False'):
        pass
```

В вашем случае будет:

```
@client.event()
async def on_member_join(member):
    role_1 = member.guild.get_role(15171165410)# ади роли которую будет получать новый юзер при входе на сервер
    await member.add_roles(role_1)
```

А если вы хотите что бы по команды то аналогично:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role_1 = member.guild.get_role(15171165410)# ади роли которую будет получать юзер
    await member.add_roles(role_1)
```

Comment: А есть такая функция для Дискорд бота, которая дает роли не новым юзерам при отправке боту сообщения

Comment: Вот есть такое решения если вы хотите не через команду но я бы вам рекомендовал делать через команды а не через событие
https://pastebin.com/DEc1LHHW

Comment: И да я бы вам порекомендовал еще раз внимательно прочитать он начала до конца эту [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), ибо у вас в коде твориться хаус)